# how to merge elements with duplicate timestamps, with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data, representing crypto transactions:

```
1599177600000,381.52,1.425,s
1599177600000,381.49,0.828,s
1599177600000,381.48,0.747,s
1599177600212,381.53,3.225,s
1599177600560,381.53,0.226,s
1599177600560,381.45,0.637,s
1599177600560,381.44,11.431,s
1599177600560,381.38,2.153,s
1599177600560,381.37,0.569,s
1599177600560,381.35,150,s
1599177600560,381.33,1.056,s
1599177600560,381.32,8.581,s
1599177600560,381.31,16.947,s
1599177600560,381.29,15.877,s
1599177600590,381.45,2.586,s
1599177600652,381.54,0.03,b
1599177600826,381.39,0.5,s
1599177601166,381.39,0.139,s
1599177601304,381.39,1.445,s
1599177601306,381.35,2.555,s
1599177601624,381.3,1.552,s
1599177601706,381.29,2,s
1599177601868,381.31,0.262,s
1599177602108,381.29,0.092,s
1599177602242,381.3,0.05,b
1599177602296,381.31,2.228,b
1599177602312,381.32,0.05,b
1599177602386,381.33,0.639,b
1599177602388,381.29,7.901,s
1599177602388,381.25,12.099,s
```

The columns are: unix timestamp (ms), price, quantity and a letter (b or s) representing if the transaction is a buy or a sell event.

Using Pandas, how can I merge the rows with the same timestamps together while adding an extra column?

The merging rule is:

```
new quantity = sum quantity for all rows
new price = sum (quantity * price) for all rows / new quantity
```

The exception is:

```
if there is a duplicate timestamp with different letters, the one with the letter 'b' has to be pushed ahead by 1ms
```

The extra column is:

```
if a row is a result of a merge, the extra columns needs to have a bool True in it
```

And then use that timestamp as an index?

I am not sure if this is doable in a single pass but also I'm not comfortable enough with Pandas' syntax to figure out how to do it, so any answer that comes with explanations would be awesome.

Edit:

Here is the desired output

```
1599177600000,381.50176,3,s,TRUE,
1599177600212,381.53,3.225,s,FALSE,
1599177600560,381.3466266,207.477,s,TRUE,
1599177600590,381.45,2.586,s,FALSE,
1599177600652,381.54,0.03,b,FALSE,
1599177600826,381.39,0.5,s,FALSE,
1599177601166,381.39,0.139,s,FALSE,
1599177601304,381.39,1.445,s,FALSE,
1599177601306,381.35,2.555,s,FALSE,
1599177601624,381.3,1.552,s,FALSE,
1599177601706,381.29,2,s,FALSE,
1599177601868,381.31,0.262,s,FALSE,
1599177602108,381.29,0.092,s,FALSE,
1599177602242,381.3,0.05,b,FALSE,
1599177602296,381.31,2.228,b,FALSE,
1599177602312,381.32,0.05,b,FALSE,
1599177602386,381.33,0.639,b,FALSE,
1599177602388,381.265802,20,s,TRUE,
```

Notice: no duplicates in the timestamps; rows that were sharing a timestamp are now merged based on the formula above and have TRUE in the new column, whereas the rows that were untouched have FALSE in the new column

Comment: Please show expected output.

Comment: @HenryYik, I added the expected output

Comment: @HenryYik, the bool column shows true if the row is the result from aggregating multiple rows; if the row is left untouched, then it should show false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
w_avg = df.groupby("time").apply(lambda d: sum(d["price"]*d["volume"])/d["volume"].sum())
s = df.loc[df["time"].duplicated(keep=False),"time"].unique()
df = df.groupby("time", as_index=False).agg({"volume": "sum"})

print (df.assign(w_avg=df["time"].map(w_avg), boolean=df["time"].isin(s)))

             time   volume       w_avg  boolean
0   1599177600000    3.000  381.501760     True
1   1599177600212    3.225  381.530000    False
2   1599177600560  207.477  381.346627     True
3   1599177600590    2.586  381.450000    False
4   1599177600652    0.030  381.540000    False
5   1599177600826    0.500  381.390000    False
6   1599177601166    0.139  381.390000    False
7   1599177601304    1.445  381.390000    False
8   1599177601306    2.555  381.350000    False
9   1599177601624    1.552  381.300000    False
10  1599177601706    2.000  381.290000    False
11  1599177601868    0.262  381.310000    False
12  1599177602108    0.092  381.290000    False
13  1599177602242    0.050  381.300000    False
14  1599177602296    2.228  381.310000    False
15  1599177602312    0.050  381.320000    False
16  1599177602386    0.639  381.330000    False
17  1599177602388   20.000  381.265802     True
```

Comment: It's almost there, but there is one issue: the price column is not an average, but a weighted average; for example the row 0 is the aggregate of row 0, 1 and 2. So the price is (price0*quantity0 + price1*quantity1 + price2*quantity2) / (quantity0+quantity1+quantity2)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is an approach that includes the business logic (use weighted average; move timestamps of buy forward one millisecond if there is buy and sell at the same time):

```
# create data frame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',')
#df['timestamp'] -= df['timestamp'].min()

# find buy, sell timestamps
buy_timestamps = df.loc[ df['buy_sell'] == 'b', 'timestamp']
sell_timestamps = df.loc[ df['buy_sell'] == 's', 'timestamp']
bs_timestamps = set(buy_timestamps) & set(sell_timestamps)

# adjust timestamps
df.loc[ df['timestamp'].isin(bs_timestamps), 'timestamp' ] += 1

# helper columns
df['price_quantity'] = df['price'] * df['quantity']
df['multiple_trades'] = df.groupby('timestamp')['buy_sell'].transform('count')
```

Now perform aggregate calculations:

```
g = df.groupby(['timestamp', 'buy_sell'])

t = (pd.concat([
    (g['price_quantity'].sum() / g['quantity'].sum()).rename('price'),
    g['quantity'].sum().rename('quantity'),
    g['timestamp'].count().apply(lambda x: True if x > 1 else False).rename('trade_count')], 
    axis=1)
     .reset_index()
     .filter(['timestamp', 'price', 'buy_sell', 'trade_count'])
    )
print(t)
```

Results are:

```
        timestamp       price buy_sell  trade_count
0   1599177600000  381.501760        s         True
1   1599177600212  381.530000        s        False
2   1599177600560  381.346627        s         True
3   1599177600590  381.450000        s        False
4   1599177600652  381.540000        b        False
5   1599177600826  381.390000        s        False
6   1599177601166  381.390000        s        False
7   1599177601304  381.390000        s        False
8   1599177601306  381.350000        s        False
9   1599177601624  381.300000        s        False
10  1599177601706  381.290000        s        False
11  1599177601868  381.310000        s        False
12  1599177602108  381.290000        s        False
13  1599177602242  381.300000        b        False
14  1599177602296  381.310000        b        False
15  1599177602312  381.320000        b        False
16  1599177602386  381.330000        b        False
17  1599177602388  381.265802        s         True
```